# TimeSpan.ParseExact ASP.NET 4 C#

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-4.0

I'm using .NET 4 and getting Input string not in correct format error when executing the following:

```
TimeSpan dropTime=TimeSpan.ParseExact("01:33 PM", "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried with the TT too, just in case but that do it. Otherwise my format seems to match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tt` is not a valid format specifier for `TimeSpan` as can be seen [on MSDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038700/timespan-parseexact-asp-net-4-c-sharp).

What you are trying to parse is a *time* not a *TimeSpan* - `PM` specifies a time of day, not a time interval (which is what `TimeSpan` represents) and cannot be parsed directly by `TimeSpan`.

You can use `DateTime` to parse this first and get the `TimeSpan` from it:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("01:33 PM", "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay
```

Comment: Thanks. So I'm assuming I need to first parse it to a DateTime.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the class `DateTime` instead:

```c#
TimeSpan dropTime=DateTime.ParseExact("01:33 PM", "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use DateTime object, please see my sample code:

```
DateTime dropTime = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParse("01:33 PM", out dropTime);
```

This will parse your string into datetime.

Best regards,
Gregor Primar